# Tutorial or video with Visual Studio.Net and Protractor

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015, protractor

I've been unable to find any videos or online tutorials for Selenium/Protractor with Visual Studio.Net.

Can someone point me to one.  An online course is fine as well, but it has to have a start to finish creation of a test solution incorporating Protractor.

NOTE: I have seen Selenium WebDriver with VS.Net tutorials, but not that use Protractor. The Protractor videos I've seen use a variety of IDE's or other tools, but not VS.Net.

F.Z.

Comment: I am also interested in this do someone know any videos?